# How can we use solve media captcha sdk in android?

Tags: android, sdk, captcha

How can we use solved media captcha sdk in android application? Is there any sample demo code for android application? Whats the process of integrating solve media library with android application?

Comment: `solved media captcha sdk` what is this?

Comment: yes solve media captcha i want to used in my android application like this : http://solvemedia.com/advertisers/mobile-type-in

Comment: and where is their SDK? Where is their documentation?

Comment: actually i have same question i am also new for this concepts and want to implement in android application if anyone can help for that

Comment: Why don't you contact `solved media` then? They know their SDK, they can answer your questions

Comment: thank you very much  @VladMatvienko will contact if cant find anything on web

Comment: @ShailendrasinhGohil   any thing u got for this  I also want to integrate into mobile environment

Comment: sorry @VishalPatel still not getting anything trying to find solution for the same

Comment: ohk let me r & d on that if i found i will inform u

Comment: ok thank you @VishalPatel  i have already post same issue in others group as well if i found then will let you know and i got one answer in one group  that the actual facilities provide by solve media that you have to implement custom in android (by your own way).